# How to connect to a Linux machine from one Linux machine, query PostgreSQL and get the data

Tags: linux, postgresql, azure

I am new to linux environment . I was looking for a script that  source(linux) machine can connect to Destination machine(linux) get the Postgre data on Destination machine. Any help here would be great. all the machines are in Azure

-B

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question as it is currently written is quite broad and may be closed. It's also unclear specifically what you're asking - there is lots of additional info that would be required to answer this question. I recommend narrowing the question by explaining what you've done so far and what problems you're having, then ask specific questions on those problems.

Comment: Thanks,  The Question is how to query a postgre Db on a linux machine from another linux machine which does not have postgre installed . I am just testing it as an external client.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is a database server, meaning you can directly connect to it over a TCP network or UNIX socket

You will need a client application or driver. In this instance it sounds like you want a client application

Your first step would be to install the `postgresql-client` package on whichever distribution of Linux you are using. For example in Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

This installs [psql](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html) which you can call on the command line like:

```
# psql -h $hostname -d $dbname -U $username -c "select ..."
```

Comment: Hello I have installed postgre on the machines , now I am trying to connect to those machines from one of the client machines ( in azure) through putty . I am Unable to connect though . all the machines have public IP assigned to them .